# SSRS export to Excel - too many columns

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export

I have a RDL report that runs on SSRS2000.

Today, I am trying to export the report to excel but the error message was:

```
Excel found unreadable content in 'filename.xls'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.
```

I have noticed there were quite a few columns so I have modified the report to have less column and it was opening up in Excel no problem.

Is there any way for users to export the data in excel and have no issues?

(All columns are necessary)

Answer (score 1):

The older verisons of Excel (up to 2003) [support a maximum of 256 columns and 65536 rows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx). This has nothing to do with Reporting Services, you can't change this. The only options I can think of:

- Make sure the report will not exceed the limit of 256 columns (including the columns the renderer generates for example for whitespace between tablixes)
- Export to XML or CSV and open/import it in Excel 2007, which can handle [16,384  columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx).